# Viewport units buggy in iOS 7

Tags: html, css, viewport, viewport-units

I am using viewport height in order to make div get all viewport. But it doesn't work in iOS. I am having very long div instead.

Here's the code:

```
#kapak
{
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#a4d186;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Viewport Units Buggyfill](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill) It solves that problem with Js.